# how to get records b/w two dates that incremented by 1 month in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Assume i have apply on 2015-01-28, then i will clear first month due on 2015-02-28 then last_paid_date will be updated to 2015-02-28, now i didn't clear due to last one month for 2015-03-28 and also today date is 2015-04-28,now i want to show two records for last one month and current month..i am stuggle with "now i want to show two records for last one month and current month"..but i think i can be solve by last paid date.i am so confuse bro ..** but entry record is only one.the last paid date only be updated while clear due..
Here is my code, but i not sure this right or wrong in php query exection.any one can tell that.

here last_paid_date updated on every month updation if updated..

```
mysql_query("
    select * from esc_electricitybill 
    where status='access' 
        && (((DATE_ADD(last_paid_date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH))>='$cur_date') 
        && ((DATE_ADD(last_paid_date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH))<='$aft_five_date'))    
        && service_type='Electricity Bill'
") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to get records where 1 month from the last paid date is between today and 5 days from now? In other words, `last_paid_date + 1 month` is after today, but before 5 days from now?

Comment: assume i have apply on 2015-01-28, then i will clear first month due on 2015-02-28 then last_paid_date will be updated to 2015-02-28, now i didn't clear due to last one month for 2015-03-28 and also today date is 2015-04-28,now i want to show two records for last one month and current month..i am stuggle with "now i want to show two records for last one month and current month"..but i think i can be solve by last paid date.i am so confuse bro ..

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what are you asking but this is the way  how to select records between a date (x) and one month (x+1 month)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    esc_electricitybill
WHERE
    last_paid_date BETWEEN $cur_date AND DATE_ADD(OrderDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Where did you get `OrderDate` from?

Comment: Sorry that was a generic example, please check now

Comment: and also i need to get records if the user not pay in last month ,it will be show last month due also with current month due..but that is my problem now how to do that..

Comment: Well,"Bro" you just shared 2 lines of your code, if you can share more, it will be appreciated

Comment: oK. can you please update the requirements of what you want to achieve in your question and I will be more than happy to help you. So far it is not clear (at least for me) what your requirements are. Examples will help too

Comment: assume i have apply on 2015-01-28, then i will  clear first month due on 2015-02-28 then last_paid_date will be updated to 2015-02-28, now i didn't clear due to last one month for 2015-03-28 and also today date is 2015-04-28,now i want to show two records for last one month and current month..i am stuggle with "now i want to show two records for last one month and current month"..but i think i can be solve by last paid date.i am so confuse bro